# how can we pass the user original query across all followup intent in dialogflow

Tags: dialog, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have one intent named "**search.category**" which has user queries like "**32gb phones**" and it has a follow up intent to **get_brand** question like "**do you have any specific brand?** ".

This can have two type of answers that user can enter brand name or he can say "I don't know."

Is there any way to pass the whole user query in main intent to followup intents.

How can we pass the original user query(32gb phones)  as a parameter across the intents?

[image]

[image]

In the second picture, you can see that two entities are selected, so is there any way to select the other text from user query ( I want the "show me some under 40000")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you would create a new [Output Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts#output_contexts) on the first intent. Output contexts created as part of an intent contain the parameters that were set by the user when they were created and are available in subsequent intents (for as long as their lifespan is active). You can access the context's parameters either in the response or in your fulfillment webhook.

If you're trying to use values that aren't set in the parameters, then in the fulfillment of the original intent you can set any value you want as a parameter of an Output Context that you create in your webhook.

Comment: But how can I get the original query from the first intent to fallback intent, the whole query?.  I am using it in fulfillment. Was trying to use by sys.any, but no hope.

Comment: So you are saying to set a contextOut parameter at the webhook end for the orginal query. "contextOut": [
    {
      "name": "original-query",
      "lifespan": 5,
      "parameters": {
        "original-query": "32gb phones"
      }
    }
  ]
in the webhook response?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it cost another webhook request, because I have not enabled the webhook of main intent and enabled only in followup intent. Is there any way without calling  webhook?

Comment: unfortunately not. if its an important value, you can capture it as a parameter, and it will be available. otherwise you have to set it.